# word patterns within an excel column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel data sets each comprising a column of word patterns and have been searching for a way to copy and group all instances of repetition within these columns into a new column.

This is the closest result I could find so far:

```
Sub Common5bis()
 Dim Joined
 Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")               'make dictionary
 d.CompareMode = 1                                          'not case sensitive
 a = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value   'data to array
 For i = 1 To UBound(a)                                     'loop trough alle records
      If Len(a(i, 1)) >= 5 Then                             'length at least 5
           For l = 1 To Len(a(i, 1)) - 4                    'all strings withing record
                s = Mid(a(i, 1), l, 5)                      'that string
                d(s) = d(s) + 1                             'increment
           Next
      End If
 Next

 Joined = Application.Index(Array(d.Keys, d.items), 0, 0)   'join the keys and the items
 With Range("D1").Resize(UBound(Joined, 2), 2)              'export range
      .EntireColumn.ClearContents                           'clear previous
      .Value = Application.Transpose(Joined)                'write to sheet
      .Sort .Range("B1"), xlDescending, Header:=xlNo        'sort descending
 End With
```

End Sub

Which yielded this result for the particular question:
[image: Result]

This example achieves 4 of the things I'm trying to achieve:

1. Identify repeating strings within a single column
2. Copies these strings into a separate column
3. Displays results in order of occurrence (in this case from least to most)
4. Displays the quantity of repetitions (including the first instance) in an adjacent column

However, although from reading the code there are basic things I've figured out that I can adapt to my purposes, it still fails to achieve these essential tasks which I'm still trying to figure out:

- Identify individual words rather than single characters

  - I could possibly reduce the size from 5 to 3, but for the word stings I have (lists of pronouns from larger texts) that would include "I I" repetitions but won't be so great for "Your You" etc, whilst at least 4 or 5 would miss anything starting with "I I"
- Include an indefinite amount of values - looking at the code and the replies to the forum it comes from it looks like it's capped at 5, but I'm trying to find a way to identify all repetitions for all multiple word strings which could be something like "I I my you You Me I You my"
- Is case sensitive - this is quite important as some words in the column have been capitalised to differentiate different uses

I'm still learning the basics of VBA but have manually typed out this example of what I'm trying to do with the code I've found above:

[image]

Intended outcome:

[image: Intended Outcome]

And so on

I'm a bit screwed at this point which is why I'm reaching out here (sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm brand new to VBA as my work almost never needs Excel, let alone macros) so will massively appreciate any constructive advice towards a solution!

Comment: What is reason not to include words `He, Me, You, Your` to your result column?

Comment: I'm hoping to only be able to single out instances of repetition between 2+ cells of a column. I'm not sure if it makes sense or is possible/practical to do but if a string of words appears for the first time in column A it'll be ignored but if it appears a second time within a cell in column A it'll be copied to column B, with both instances counted (in this case, 2) in column C

Comment: For this piece of research I'm expecting the list in column C will start with very many shorter strings e.g. column B "me You" C "89", and then as the list continues and strings get longer the number in C will decrease - e.g. B "you we I You we You" C "4"

Comment: Why are you excluding the patterns `my I` and `I my`?

Comment: Apologies that was a mistake as I tried to type the example out by hand. Will try and update the image for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I've been working with it recently, I note that you can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

First add a custom function:

- New blank query
- Rename per the code comment

***Edits to make case-insensitive***

***Custom Function***

```
//rename fnPatterns
//generate all possible patterns of two words or more
(String as text)=>

let

//split text string into individual words & get the count of words
    #"Split Words" = List.Buffer(Text.Split(String," ")),
    wordCount = List.Count(#"Split Words"),

//start position for each number of words
    starts = List.Numbers(0, wordCount-1),

//number of words for each pattern (minimum of two (2) words in a pattern
    words = List.Reverse(List.Numbers(2, wordCount-1)),

//generate patterns as index into the List and number of words
//   will be used in the List.Range function
    patterns = List.Combine(List.Generate(
        ()=>[r={{0,wordCount}}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < wordCount-1,
        each [r=List.Transform({0..starts{[idx]+1}}, (li)=> {li, wordCount-[idx]-1}), 
                idx=[idx]+1],
        each [r]
    )),

//Generate a list of all the patterns by using the List.Range function
    wordPatterns = List.Distinct(List.Accumulate(patterns, {}, (state, current)=>
        state & {List.Range(#"Split Words", current{0}, current{1})}), Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)        
    
    
in
    wordPatterns
```

***Main Function***

```
let

//change next line to reflect data source
//if data has a column name other than "Column1", that will need to be changed also wherever referenced
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Create a list of all the possible patterns for each string, added as a custom column
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Patterns", each fnPatterns([Column1]), type list),

//removed unneeded original column of strings
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"Column1"}),

//Expand the column of lists of lists into a column of lists
    #"Expanded Patterns" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Patterns"),

//convert all lists to lower case for text-insensitive comparison
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Patterns", "lower case patterns", 
        each List.Transform([Patterns], each Text.Lower(_))),

//Count number of matches for each pattern
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Count", each List.Count(List.Select(#"Added Custom"[lower case patterns], (li)=> li = [lower case patterns])), Int64.Type),

//Filter for matches of more than one (1)
//  then remove duplicate patterns based on the "lower case pattern" column
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Count] > 1)),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"lower case patterns"}),

//Remove lower case pattern column and sort by count descending
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"lower case patterns"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Count", Order.Descending}}),

//Re-construct original patterns as text
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows", 
        {"Patterns", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

[image]

*Note that you could readily implement a similar algorithm using VBA, the `VBA.Split` function and a Dictionary*

Comment: Amazing this is exactly what I need! It looks like the system admin has turned off Insider Builds so am asking her to give me access so I can open the PQ editor rather than just the Get Data window, and then should be able to try this in a couple of hours

Comment: To clarify, once I've opened the advanced editor do I copy in the code titled Main Function and then start an empty query to input the Custom Function?

Comment: I think I've figured it out, but keep getting this error when copying in the Main Function code "[Expression.Error] The import fnPatterns matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?". The Applied Steps window shows this happens from the Expand line, but I can't find anything that would be causing it. If relevant, I'm using the latest version of Excel for mac from the Apple App Store

Comment: @Yohane WRT your first comment, the answer is Yes you do.  WRT to your second question, you'll get that error if you haven't yet pasted in (and re-named) the custom function, but ***not on that line***.   Make sure all the code is there and re-check.  Once you get it working as is, I still need to make the query case-insensitive.

Comment: @Yohane I have edited the code to make the routine case-insensitive.  You should re-copy both.

Comment: I imagine I'm doing something quite stupid (many many apologies) but these are the steps I'm taking so far, but still getting the error: 1. Opening PQ and selecting the table (named "Yohane" for simplicity's sake). 2. Opened advanced editor and replaced code with your Main Function code. 3. Replaced the name "Table 17" with table name "Yohane" - name of column is Column1 as in the code, so I'm not sure there's anything else I should change

Comment: Looking at the Applied Steps after hitting OK the first 3 steps (Changed Type-Removed Columns) looks fine. From the next step "Expanded Patterns" till the end is just the Expression.Error message. 4. In the Queries list on the left, right click=>new query=>more...=>blank query. 5. replaced code with Custom Function code. hit Next 6. This takes me to the Enter Parameter page. 7. Enter "Column1" into String textbook. 8. press Invoke - this creates an invoked function with an empty list and the Expression.Error message remains

Comment: @Yohane `Removed Columns` should be the fourth step, not the third.  There's no need to enter anything on the `Enter Parameters` page.  Are you sure you renamed the custom function properly?

Comment: Ah I think that's where I'm going wrong. Is this related to //Rename fnPatterns on the first line of the Custom Function? "Table17" in the Main Function was changed to "Yohane" and "Column1" in subsequent lines is left as is. I've also tried changing the Custom Function name in the Queries Pane list on the left to Yohane, which wasn't allowed as that matches the Table name, and to Column1, but yielded no result

Comment: @Yohane You need to rename the custom function so that the name of the custom function is **`fnPatterns`**

Comment: Thanks sorry for not catching that. Have also spent a couple of hours making my data as clean as possible and with the correct name Applied Steps 1-7 "(Source-Added Custom1) have no errors, and subsequent steps have error ([Expression.Error] We cannot convert the value null to type List.
Details
isRecoverable: True
isExpected: True". I've triple checked source data for empty cells so am wondering if that might be referring to a value in the code, although that would be strange as you've already shown it works perfectly

Comment: All cells under "Count" in the Added Custom1 step also have [error] instead of [list], but I assume that's because the following steps didn't yet execute

Comment: @Yohane I'd be willing to bet that if you scrolled down your column of Lists, you'd see some errors. I'm guessing that your data not only has blank cells, but also cells with only a single word.  Both of those situations will return the error you are seeing (and there were no examples in your data).  You could clean your data by inserting steps after `#"Changed Type"` to add a column with the word count; filter by selecting those rows with a wordcount > 1 (i.e. 2 or more), then deleting the word count column.

Comment: Thank you 1 billionX over. I didn't realise at first that single words affected it, got rid of those, still had the issue but after much experimentation and trial and error found a single hyphen where there should have been a space. After all you've done I won't even attempt to bother you for capitalisation as the outputs I'm getting will be relatively sort for outliers. Many many thanks!